# making an unique column value after order by mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

So, my problem is that I have a list of customers (table now has around 100k records) with income per each customer. When I group it by country I get around 60 countries with sum of income. Than I need to order it by the income DESC, my query looks something like this:

```
SELECT s2.i,s1.year,s1.short_c,s1.country,s1.uges FROM
(SELECT u.year,k.short_c,s.country, IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(u.income)),0) as uges 
    FROM im_income u,im_contact k,td_countries s
    WHERE u.year=2012
    AND u.customer_id=k.id
    AND k.kat='K'
    AND k.short_c=s.short_c
    GROUP BY k.short_c, u.year
    ORDER BY u.year ASC,uges DESC) s1
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT @i:=@i+1 as i FROM (SELECT @i:= 0) AS i) s2
```

And I know that this with CROSS JOIN is wrong since it is not giving me what I need, but is there a way to make an unique id after ORDER BY since I need to order countries with income DESC and than assing them id that would represent a rank number???

Result looks like this now:

```
+-+----+-------+---------+------+
|i|year|short_c|country  |uges  |
+-+----+-------+---------+------+
|1|2012|USA    |United S.|123456|
+-+----+-------+---------+------+
|1|2012|RU     |Russia   |23456 |
+-+----+-------+---------+------+
```

And I would want it in this way, but to assign after order by the unique i value:

```
+-+----+-------+---------+------+
|i|year|short_c|country  |uges  |
+-+----+-------+---------+------+
|1|2012|USA    |United S.|123456|
+-+----+-------+---------+------+
|2|2012|RU     |Russia   |23456 |
+-+----+-------+---------+------+
|3|    |       |         |      |
+-+----+-------+---------+------+
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT @i := @i + 1 as i, s1.year, s1.short_c, s1.country, s1.uges
FROM (SELECT u.year, 
             k.short_c, 
             s.country, 
             IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(u.income)),0) as uges 
      FROM im_income u join
           im_contact k
           on u.customer_id = k.id join
           td_countries s
           on k.short_c = s.short_c
      WHERE u.year = 2012 AND k.kat = 'K'
      GROUP BY k.short_c, u.year
     ) s1
     CROSS JOIN 
     (SELECT @i:= 0) const
ORDER BY year, uges desc;
```

The variable evaluation occurs when the results are being "output", after the order by.

I also fixed your `join` syntax.  You should learn to use the explicit `join` rather than implicit joins in the `where` clause.